# pass on confact 7 form values to another contact 7 form

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i have a many contact  7 forms on my website but i want to pass on some values inputted by user of  job data form to appear on invoice data form as default and it should be editable?

Comment: You can try session in this also there is option in cf7 to get and set values https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/

Answer (score 2):

can you try this by session using the cf7 function

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'sent_cf7_data');

    function sent_cf7_data($cf) 
    {
        if(session_id() == '') {
        session_start();
      }
        $current_submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        $_SESSION['cf7_submission'] = $current_submission->get_posted_data();

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i have  other forms on my site. Though i am only interested in auto filling invoice data form from job data form.

Comment: you can get the fields values 'echo $_SESSION['cf7_submission']['name'];'

Comment: ok pardon me for askimg. where will i place the above  code? Secondly i want the values auto filled on the invoice data form to be editable?

Comment: in themes/your_theme/functions.php file ..these values you can get on next page by session

Comment: where  should i add this code echo $_SESSION['cf7_submission']['name'];